# How to install Caddy on Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: amazon-linux, caddy

Before upgrading to [Amazon Linux 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/), I'd like to make sure I can easily install [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/).

Amazon published a [list of available packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages.html), but Caddy is not in it.
I also found a [package request from 2022](https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/95) asking to add Caddy, but it went stale.

Does anyone know how to install Caddy on Amazon Linux 2023?

Answer (score 0):

You can use static binaries. You can also check on https://caddyserver.com/docs/install#static-binaries

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).